# Drupal, Gmap Not working with Firefox. But fine with Chrome

Tags: drupal

I am working first time on drupal and I have a little problem with gmap. When I check this on chrome its perfect, on firefox icons are displaying but map is not.

Can any one tell me what is the problem ? or i have to use alternate? here is the link of example: http://www.unscalped.com/node/36

```
Timestamp: 3/7/2012 5:02:41 PM
Error: Image corrupt or truncated: <unknown>
Source File: <unknown>
Line: 0

I got also this error in ERROR CONSOLE
```

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using? I can see the GMap fine on my Firefox.

Comment: i am using firefox 13.0.1. but now its solve. so you can see the map on site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the Answer,

```
.gmap img{max-width:none;}
```

this CSS line solve my problem. the property of image was set inherited **max-width:100%;** just need to set max-width to none, i think it will be helpful for others if anyone have problem on viewing map.